# In Objective C, how can I have subclasses inherit static class variables that, if set, won't change the variable's value for all children?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, static, class-variables

In Objective C, how can I have subclasses inherit static class variables that, if set, won't change the variable's value for all children?

Lets say I have abstract class Car. It has a static BOOL, "isSportsCar", that we set to zero.

Then in subclass SportsCar's init method, we set isSportsCar = YES.

My goal was so that all instances of SportsCar will return "YES" from the method, "isSportsCar" (which returns the static BOOL's value).

The problem is that all the other subclasses of Car, like LuxuryCar and Limousine, all now return YES from "isSportsCar".

I want to avoid having to declare the isSportsCar methods in all the subclasses.

But how can I make a class variable where each subclass will have its own instance of that variable?

Comment: Just to make your question a little clearer, can you provide a code snippet that would show the *desired behavior*? Like a unit test that would verify the behavior of the implementation that you are asking for in your question?

Comment: Objective-C classes don't (and can't) have class variables, so that variable should probably be an instance variable set in the `init` method.

Comment: *I want to avoid having to declare the isSportsCar methods in all the subclasses.* Probably you want to avoid defining an instance method on all subclasses, because you can declare it at the base class. However, why do you want to avoid it? What makes doing so worse compared to set a variable on all subclasses?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - The reason I want to avoid it is to keep my code as DRY as possible. Keep repeated code to a minimum.

Comment: Setting the instance variable is repetitive, too, isn't it? However, you can have a middle class.

Comment: See the correct answer, that works very well for what I'm trying to achieve. (Which is to have some instances of child-classes of my abstract custom CoreData NSManagedObject subclass always know whether or not they should be included in a web sync operation or if they're just local cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this using a static variable. Use a class method. So in the abstract base class `Car` you have:

Car.h:

```
+ (BOOL)isSportsCar;
```

Car.m:

```
+ (BOOL)isSportsCar {
    return NO;
}
```

Then in your `SportsCar` class you have:

SportsCar.m:

```
+ (BOOL)isSportsCar {
    return YES;
}
```

Then only classes inherited from `SportsCar` will return `YES`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, because the question specified that it needed to be a *class* variable. And a cool thing in Objective C is that you can use dot syntax on these, like you can write: `if(Limousine.isSportsCar) { ... }`. If I want a pseudo-iVar out of it, I can have another method: `- (BOOL)isSportsCar { return [[self class] performSelector:@selector(isSportsCar)]; }` I could even override what this returns if `isSoupedUpAndPimpedOut` is true :D

Answer (score 1):

You can't. At least not with static variables.

The idea of static variable are that they are values on the classes themselves, not the instances. So logically there will be one value across all instances, regardless of whether those instances are of the class where the variable was defined, or instances of subclasses. To have different values, you need to create instance variables or properties. Then the value can be different.

For example, you could define readonly properties and code a getter to return a hard coded value like this:

```
@interface Car:NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly, getter=isSportsCar) BOOL sportsCar;
@end

@implementation Car 
-(BOOL) isSportsCar {
    return NO;
}
@end

@interface SportsCar:Car
@end

@implementation SportsCar 
-(BOOL) isSportsCar {
    return YES;
}
@end
```

However from the context of what you say, I suspect you want to known when you are dealing with a `SportsCar` in you code. Something like this:

```
if (car.isSportsCar) {...}
```

This is fine if you have various types of cards which can be sports cars, all running with the same class. But if you are creating different classes, you might want to save yourself the code and simply test the class itself:

```
if ([car isKindOfClass:[SportsCar class]]) {...}
```

Even if you then add a `Bugatti` class derived from a `SportsCar` class, this will still work. It all comes down to what you are trying to achieve.

My finally recommendation would be to remember the KISS principle and avoid creating variables or properties that effectively duplicate other data.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution only fails to work because you used a static variable. If you had defined an instance variable, or a property, on the base class, then your scheme works.

Your base `Car` class does what it does now - sets the instance variable/property `isSportsCar` to `NO` in its `init` method. Any instance of `Car`, or any of its subclasses, now has a property `isSportsCar` which returns `NO`.

The `init` method of your subclass `SportsCar` first calls the `init` method of its superclass using `[super init]` - which sets `isSportsCar` to `NO`, then does its now initialising and sets `isSportsCar` to `YES`. Now for any instance of `SportsCar`, or any of its subclasses, `isSportCar` will return `YES`.

If you use a property for `isSportsCar` you can declare it as `readonly` in the public header file, and as `readwrite` in a private header file only subclasses import. That way subclasses can set the property but all others can only read it.

Using a property/instance variable is only required if the value might change. In the case of `isSportsCar` it is unlikely to change for a particular class. In that case you can just use an instance method, overriding as required in subclasses. So `Car` would contain:

```
- (BOOL) isSportsCar { return NO; }
```

and `SportsCar` would contain:

```
- (BOOL) isSportsCar { return YES; }
```

as with the property approach inheritance handles the rest and instances of `Car`, or any of its subclasses *except* `SportsCar`, return `NO`; while instances of `SportsCar`, and any of its subclasses, return `YES`.

HTH